# Joomla 3 MySQLi delete query syntax

Tags: php, joomla, mysqli

I'm working on a script within a Joomla 3 component and need to have a mysqli delete query, but it's not working. No errors either... it just doesn't seem to do anything. Here's what I have:

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$conditions = array(
  $db->quoteName('id') . ' = 50',
  $db->quoteName('id') . ' = 54',
  $db->quoteName('id') . ' = 73',
  $db->quoteName('id') . ' = 86',
  $db->quoteName('id') . ' = 92'
);

$query->delete($db->quoteName('#__menu'))->where($conditions);

$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->query();
```

The $conditions array is much longer than this, but I shortened it for this post. I assume my query is missing something, but I can't find anything anywhere that shows exactly what I'm doing here. This same setup works fine for other queries, just not this delete one. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why the down vote - clearly asked with formatted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolved SQL is `id=50 AND id=54 AND id=73` - of course no record has an ID that matches that. You would want `id=50 OR id=54 OR id=73....`

There may be a more "Joomla Correct" way of doing it, but his will give you the right WHERE clause:

```
$query->where('`id` IN (50,54,73,86,92)';
```

Comment: Thanks @GDP! The issue WAS that it was processing as AND instead of OR. I was able to get this to work by changing the query to: 
`$query->delete($db->quoteName('#__menu'))->where($conditions, 'OR');`

Comment: @N8Dog - Been there, done that...spent a day reading Mysql docs once only to find the same mistake on my end.  Learned lots, but felt silly.  Nice to see the Joomla way of specifying the OR - never had the need for it, but will be handy.  Also, it's customary to formally accept the answer if it solved the problem to boost your (and my) reputation. :)

Comment: Also, if you've got other Joomla questions, there's a new SE site dedicated to Joomla - http://joomla.stackexchange.com.  That's where all the gurus are hanging out these days!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have already done so, but you don't appear to have defined `$db`. See the code below:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
```

In addition to this, you are defining `$db->query()` using the variable `$results` but don't appear to be calling it. I would also suggest replacing `query` with `execute` as it's deprecated.

So below would be your final code:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$conditions = array(
  $db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . $db->quote('50'),
  $db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . $db->quote('54'),
  $db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . $db->quote('73'),
  $db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . $db->quote('86'),
  $db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . $db->quote('92')
);

$query->delete($db->quoteName('#__menu'))
      ->where($conditions);

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks, but still not there. First, I didn't include the $db definition here as I saw it as a given. That is there. I did change to $db->execute(); but still the query seems to not be running.

Comment: Are you putting this code within a function? If so, are you calling the function correctly? Turn on error reporting in your Global Configuration to maximum and see what happens. This code is correct therefore if it's not working, it something else that you're doing incorrectly

Comment: As I was learning to use $query, I was putting in a `echo $query->dump()` immediately before executing it so that I could see if the SQL was correct, and I was able to try it mySQL as well.   I also often added `die`; to insure that the line of code was actually being executed.  A little Neanderthal, but it usually worked, lol.

Comment: The dump is showing me:

    DELETE FROM `xxx_menu` WHERE `id` = 50 AND `id` = 54 AND `id` = 73 AND `id` = 86 AND `id` = 92

After the query I have another echo statement which is showing... and a die. It ends there, no errors and error reporting is set to all.

Comment: @N8Dog - I've updated the code in my answer. You will see now that the condition ID values are now escaped using `quote()`. Please try this, and if it doesn't work, try using the conditions that are commented out just below

Comment: @Lodder I tried the changes given. The first option still did nothing. The 2nd commented out option gives an error... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in... I have it just like your answer shows.

Comment: Ah damn. My mistake. Remove the dot after (int) ... I will do a proper test when Im back home